# Changing the look of div/img

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code of the first picture (the green one). I want to modify the boxes to look like the boxes in the picture 2 (the one with the red in the middle).

Should I add another class to the `img` or `id? How can I modify the boxes in first pic so they will look like the ones in the second pic?

What kind of code I am supposed to write in CSS file to change the look of them?

[image: second pic[![][2]]
[image: first pic[![][1]]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

```css
.carousel-item{
  position: absolute;
  background:green;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'functionality/imageslider.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'blog/imageslider.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-item" id="one"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" id="two"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" id="three"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" id="four"
        ><img
          src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg"
         alt=""/>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: width, height, z-index, box-shadow are the properties you will need to use. I will leave it to you to experiment with these

Comment: like @sinanspd mentioned. After you try those out and can't figure it out, then write out another question with the attempt at using those.

Comment: @sinanspd, thank you man, i did try those, and the problem i am facing right now is, when i play with the height and width, it changes all of them, though i want only those on the side to be a bit smaller. is there anything that i am missing? :/

Comment: @uingtea, what do you mean? 0.o

Comment: First of all, edit your question with what you have tried, we can not randomly guess what has gone wrong. Tho an educated guess would be you are styling ```.carousel-item```, you need to style them individually through ```id``` or ```nth-child```

Comment: I agree with @sinanspd. However, for a bit more clarity, what they are saying is that each of your div classes are the same ("carousel-item") so when you change the styling for one in your CSS, it changes them for all on your web page. You can try by altering the ID styling (for example, .carousel-item #two {} in your CSS as a start.)